# Using ng-if in a custom directive template causing trouble to bind resizing event to element

Tags: angularjs, jquery-ui, angularjs-directive, resize, angular-ng-if

Im putting my Pop-UP ( i.e bootstrap pop up)  directive multiple time on a page. The pop up appear only if `ng-if` is true, sent as attribute parameter,but the **jQuery** resizing function is not binded to the element in link function of the directive.

This my first line of HTML in my directive

```
<div  class='ng-modal' id='Modal1' ng-if='show'>
```

The **show** is true when I click a button,the pop appear in UI but

```
$('#ModalDialog').resizable()
```

is not fired upon. 
Although if I do something like this

```
$timeout(function () {$('#Modal1').resizable() }, 1000);
```

then it work fine but `$timeout` function is not allowed in my code. 
what would be the proper technique to do this?

My finding: the problem only arise when the directive is putted multi-time on a a page, single call with `ng-show` causing no trouble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since JQuery relies on existing DOM elements, during the execution of

```
$('#ModalDialog').resizable()
```

An element with "#ModalDialog" might or might not exist.
I am not familiar with JQuery resizable but when you need to apply JQuery on elements in angular the best practice is creating a **directive** and working with the DOM in the **link** function. This will ensure non-angular behaviour is properly applied to an element.

```
.directive('uiResizable', function() {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: ...,
    templateUrl: ...,
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        element.resizable();
    }
  };
});
```

And to apply JQuery resizable to an element:

```
<div id="#ModalDialog" ui-resizable ng-if ...>
```

I hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks for the response, and yes you are right and I did it the same, but if I put the directive only one time in the HTML markup then it work fine and the resizing done perfectly, but if I put it multiple time with different attributes parameters then the resizing function does not applied and I think, when I change the value of scope variable **show**  from false to true then then the  DOM render but after the resizing function.
Although the resizing function is placed inside the **post link** function.

Comment: You could try putting a breakpoint just before applying .resizable() and check if the selected element is rendered and points to the right DOM element (chrome will highlight it too i believe). Make sure if you're using it multiple times it gets applied to different elements.

Comment: no need to put ui-resizable and use ng-show but I strictly did the trick to used the element param of the link function



 `angular.element(element[0].querySelector('#zdaasModalDialog1'))
                .resizable({
                    minHeight: scope.minHeightModalDialog, // calculated in init ftn
                    minWidth: scope.minInnerWidth, // calculated in init ftn
                    resize: function (event, ui) {
     //....
                    }
                });`